# Why all my Hbase Regionservers are down

Tags: hbase

All of my HbaseRegion Servers were crashed(stopped), because of the following Exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:441)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:434)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.<init>(SocketChannelImpl.java:105)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openSocketChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:60)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.StandardSocketFactory.createSocket(StandardSocketFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1620)
```

But I did increase the OS user File Descriptor to 65535, and give Hbase the number is 55535, how come Hbase still crashed on this config?

I was trying to insert 20Million big rows to Hbase, each row may has 1MB-10MB, the first 10Million records ran well, but the second 10Million records caused Hbase crashed.

Answer (score 2):

Per HBase documentation [HBase Configuration](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/configuration.html#ulimit) you should be able to check if the ulimit you *believe* to set was really set:

> Also, a common mistake is that administrators will up the file descriptors for a particular user but for whatever reason, HBase will be running as some one else. HBase prints in its logs as the first line the ulimit its seeing. Ensure its correct.